# Netbeans Not Formatting Compile Instructions - C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8

Netbeans is not forming the compile instructions correctly. The line below is the compile instructions.

```
g++ -m64    -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/firebirdconnection_test build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -lall_in_one.cpp -static
```

and you can see that it is not putting the space between -l and all_in_one.cpp.

This there anyway to modify the build instructions to allow for that space?

Comment: the `-l` switch does not require a space, but that's used for linking.  Are you specifying `all_in_one.cpp` as a library to link to vs. a file to compile?

Comment: I am adding it as a library in the "Linker" section of the project properties.

Comment: Don't do that - a .cpp file is not a library.  It is a source file.